# Send info from UIViewRepresentable back to SwiftUI (SpriteKit)

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, uikit, swiftui

I'm building **with SwiftUI** an app with 3 main pages.
When you open the app, you are greeted with a **SpriteKit view** that lets you choose which of these 3 pages you want to visit.

=> Is it possible send the selected page name **from SpriteKit to SwiftUI**? And if it is, how?

Thanks a lot, any help would be appreciated ! I've spend way too long on this rather simple looking problem D:

*Additional info:*

- I use UIViewRepresentable to embed my SKView in SwiftUI
- The page name that I want to get back is stored in the name of the SKNodes (but I can change that if needed)
- I use SpriteKit because I need 2D physics, animations, etc...
- I'm pretty new to swift, but not to programming

*What I've tried so far:*

- storing the page name in a @Binding variable and setting up a Coordinator for my UIViewRepresentable (based on the doc, 'Integrating SwiftUI' and a few guides I randomly found online). However I don't use UIKitRatingsControl (used in the WWDC talk*) or MapKit (often used in the guides I found online), but SpriteKit; and I can't get this to work

*https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/231/ from 14:55 to 18:05

Comment: * A `@Binding` should work - it's even possible to pass the `@Binding` down to the `SKView` as long as you `@import SwiftUI` to the `SKView` file. `@ObservedObject` also worked in `UIKit` and `SpriteKit` views

Comment: Thanks a lot @Romy, I am going to look further into bindings )

Comment: update: I finally got it to work by passing a state var down to the view as you said. Thank you very much @RomyIlano !